# iOS SpriteKit prevent dim when the game is not paused

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Currently my application (while still playing) suddenly dims. My game is controller with the accelerometer, no touch contact while playing the game.

I have tried adding

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

to my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on the app delegate.
But this will stop the app from dimming (anytime) but all I want is to not dim unless the game is paused.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious? Disable the idle timer only when the game begins. Enable it again when the game is paused or ends. It's not a "once-only and never again" kind of switch.

Comment: amazingly I'm currently watching your tutorial videos. :) I just started with game development in general.